# Does iOS Sqlite database get locked in simultaneous background and foreground operation?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am making iOS app which is having both background and foreground database operations.
I am getting 'Database locked' exception.
The one most common scenario is -when my app inserting/updating/fetching data from database in background at same time if I am fetching data from database in foreground database gets locked.
I am using raw sqlite queries.

- I have made one common class for Database operation, do I need to
  make it singleton class?
- Does such type of operation are done using sqlite in iOS?
- I have read about THREAD_SAFE for sqlite, but not getting how to do
  THREAD_SAFE.

Any other approach is also appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I just recently overcame a similar problem. I too am working on an app with many concurrent queries. I was getting a lot of SQLITE errors until I did the following two things:

1. Switch the Journal Mode to WAL (write-ahead logging). By default the journal mode is 'rollback journal'. It is my understanding that WAL allows you to make reads from the database while a write is happening. You can read about WAL [here](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html). WAL DOES NOT allow you to make concurrent writes.
2. Make sure only 1 thread can write to your DB at a time. Even if threads are writing to different tables, they should only be able to do so in a serial manner. The easiest/cleanest way to do this in my opinion is to use `dispatch_barrier_synch` with a common GCD queue (i.e singleton). So for instance, anytime you are performing a write query, you should execute it like this:

   ```
   dispatch_barrier_sync(singletonQueue, ^{
       sqlite3_step(yourWriteStatement);
   });
   ```

There are other ways to accomplish this concurrency but this way worked for me.